# JTS GeometryClipper returns wrong results

Tags: java, clip, geotools

I have envelopes and a polygon and I want to split that polygon using the envelope geometries. My code is like this:

```
val arr = new ArrayBuffer[Polygon]
for (h in polygons){
    val ex =  h.envelope
    val cellEnvp = new Envelope ( ex.Xmin, ex.Ymin, ex.Xmax, ex.Ymax )
    val clipper = new GeometryClipper ( cellEnvp )
    val clip = clipper.clipSafe( h.jtsGeom, false, 0.001)
    if (clip != null && !clip.isEmpty) {
      arr += clip.asInstanceOf[com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Polygon] 
    }
  }
```

The thing is that the result is OK, but it adds in each polygon a little part from the envelope. Why...?
[image]

UPADATE: if I use true, I see the above results 
 1. Now, it returns polygons and also Multipolygons 
 2. I loose some clips

Results: [image]The red polygons are the one that missing

Answer (score 1):

Update 2: 
Finally, I get to manage the results using the above code

```
    val cellEnvp = new Envelope(MinX, MaxX, MinY, MaxY)
    val clipper = new GeometryClipper(cellEnvp)
    val clip = clipper.clipSafe(h.jtsGeom, false, 0.00001)
    if ( clip != null && !clip.isEmpty ) {
      if ( clip.isSimple ) {
          arr += (r -> Polygon(clip.asInstanceOf[jts.Polygon]))
      }
      else {
          clip.normalize
          arr += (r -> Polygon(clip.asInstanceOf[jts.Polygon]).simplify(0.0001))

      }
    }
```

Just, the polygons that are not simple, there must be first simplify

Comment: Don't forget to accept your answer by clicking the green-faded tick on the left-hand side :)

Answer (score 0):

Without checking [the code](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/master/modules/library/main/src/main/java/org/geotools/geometry/jts/GeometryClipper.java) in detail I can't say what causes it but I suspect the hint in the docs gives a clue:

> ensureValid - If false there is no guarantee the polygons returned will be valid according to JTS rules (but should still be good enough to be used for pure rendering)

If you set the value to `true` you should see clips like:
[image]

Comment: please edit the question with additional information, note returning a multipolygon is perfectly valid in some cases also points can be returned.